# Redirect after logging in not Working Properly

Tags: reactjs

Please i'm trying to redirect a user after logging in and it seems I'm doing something wrong because after logging in it doesn't redirect to the next page until i manually refresh the page

Here is the Signin component:

```
class Signin extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };
  
  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.props.isAuthenticated)
  if(this.props.isAuthenticated) return <Redirect to= '/'/>
  }

  user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.login(this.state);
  };
  render() {
if(this.user) return <Redirect  to ='/'/>
    return (
      <Grid textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" className="app">
        <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}>
          <Header as="h2" icon textAlign="center">
            <Icon name="code branch" className="headerColor" />
            <div className="headerColor">Login to ProGela</div>
          </Header>
          <Form size="large" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="form">
            <Segment stacked>
              <Form.Input
                fluid
                id="email"
                icon="user"
                iconPosition="left"
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                required
                type="email"
              />
              <Form.Input
                fluid
                id="password"
                icon="lock"
                iconPosition="left"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                required
                type="password"
              />
              <Button color="red" className="headerColor" fluid size="large">
                Sumit
              </Button>
            </Segment>
          </Form>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return{
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Signin);
```

i tried so many things, like i checked for the user if is present in the localstorage then let it redirect, check if user isAuthenicated from props, used that with componentDidUpdate Hooks still no progress

Comment: presumably your `login` function sets the user item in local storage? does it do any state updates in that function? if you don't update the state and pass new props down, the component won't be updated and the render function won't be called and `if(this.user) return <Redirect  to ='/'/>` won't be returned

Comment: @TomFinney Thanks for your comment it helped. But after using `isAuthenicated` from the store i have this error

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```